# iOS App store submission - Can I submit a facebook test user account information to apple

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, app-store

I just submitted my first iOS app to the apple app store.
My app is facebook login only, so I am assuming the reviewers will ask for a test account.

Can I create a facebook test user account and provide apple with the username and password, so that they can login? I am not sure if facebook has a policy against giving out the username and password to other companies (in this case, Apple).

Comment: What did you do at the end? Have you considered an anonymous login option for your app with FB API 2?

Answer (score 2):

For FB login, you do not need to supply any test user credentials to Apple. They will use their test accounts for same. I have submitted lot of applications with Fb login on app store and it has never been any issue with Review team.

Comment: Was fb your only login and was login required for full access?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had facebook only log in, and I created a new facebook account for the testers to use.  I'm not sure if this agrees with facebook's policy, but with a test account, they'd need a way to login which means they'd need access to your facebook developer account.

Just submit the email and password for the account you created.

Source: Personal experience -- It passed.

Comment: it's not OK according to Facebook's policy, but I've never heard of anyone being penalized, and if the account isn't used for spam I'd figure they just appreciate the registration inflating their numbers.

Comment: Logan, did you create a test user account or a whole new facebook account. 
I just finished creating test user accounts and i was able to login using those accounts and use my app.  
Just not sure if i can give apple access to those test user accounts. Yours and Stefan's answers suggests that even though it might not be officially allowed, it is fine to do so.

Comment: You'll have to create an all new account. To access your Facebook test accounts you'd have to access the developer account associated with them. As far as I know there's no way to create an actual login (email and password) for a Facebook test account.

Comment: @Logan So if my Facebook App is set to allow public access, you suggest to simply create a Facebook account, and give the account to Apple? Apple testers have an account for tests, but I just got rejected since they pressed "Don't Allow" and it didn't login... WTF?!

Comment: @thedp - Bummer about rejection! All I can tell you is my personal experience.  That is what I did, and it passed. Is that the description they gave for the rejection?

Comment: @Logan I am guessing he was monitoring who's allowing and who is not. Maybe they expecting you to provide an anonymous access to have an overview of the app before logging?! right? Since FB API v2 gives you that option. But I am carious to know what they said for rejection.